# Why is this map function not returning one of the number, when it gets 1 to subtract from using GAS?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I'm getting the numbers in a column and subtracting 1 from it, when the value it not empty:

```
function myFunction(){
const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
const colSettingSheet = ss.getSheetByName('Settings');
let colSettings = colSettingSheet.getRange('D4:E').getValues();

let indexes = colSettings.map(e => e[1] > 0 ? e[1] - 1 : e[1]).filter(e => e != '');
}
```

The original values:

`[[6,7,8,1,,,,14,31,17,30,15,16,34]]`

This is what it's returning:

```
[5,6,7,13,30,16,29,14,15,33]
```

...and it's missing a `0` between `7` and `13` and I can't find out why.

Appreciate your input!

Comment: It's being removed by the filter `e != ''`. When you compare a number with a string, the string is converted to a number, and an empty string converts to `0`.

Comment: if you want 0 to stay in array, it's better to move filter before the map, so you will not need to work with empty values, use `!==` instead of `!=`, so JS will not try to convert types

Comment: What's the purpose of that filter? There are no strings in your array.

Comment: @Barmar I guess, it's used to remove empty values

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need filter out `undefined`, not empty string.

And as Alexey Zelenin suggested, `filter` and `map` should be swapped

```js
let colSettings = [6,0,7,8,1,,,,14,31,17,30,15,16,34].map(a => [0,a]);
let indexes = colSettings.filter(e => e !== undefined).map(e => e[1] > 0 ? e[1] - 1 : e[1]);
console.log(indexes);
```

And since `filter` automatically removes empty items, you can use `filter(Boolean)` instead.

[EDIT]
You don't really need loop twice through the array with `filter` and `map`, you can use `reduce` and filter it in one shot:

```js
let colSettings = [6,0,7,8,1,,,,14,31,17,30,15,16,34].map(a => [0,a]);
let indexes = colSettings.reduce((r,a) => ((r[r.length] = a[1] - (a[1] && 1)), r), []);
console.log(indexes);
```

P.S.
Your original code suggests that the original array format is different then you've posted, it's more like:
`[[0,6],[0,7],[0,8],[0,1],,,,[0,14],[0,31],[0,17],[0,30],[0,15],[0,16],[0,34]]`

If the array is actual in format you've posted `[[6,7,8,1,,,,14,31,17,30,15,16,34]]` than the code for that would be:

```js
let colSettings = [[6,0,7,8,1,,,,14,31,17,30,15,16,34]];
let indexes = colSettings.map(ar => ar.reduce((r,a) => ((r[r.length] = a - (a && 1)), r), []));
console.log(indexes);
```

Comment: I'd suggest swapping `filter` and `map` operators

Comment: @AlexeyZelenin good catch!

Comment: Tried getting rid of the empty values with the answer above. Something like: ```colSettings.filter(e => e !== undefined || e !== "").map...```, but it didn't work. Thank you!

Comment: @santosOnit this condition would always be true, because according to your original post the array contains only numbers and `undefined` values. So, checking against an empty string will always be true. To make sure you are getting the types you think, check it with something like this: `colSettings.map((a,i) => console.log(i, '"'+a+'"', typeof a))`

Answer (score 0):

#### This works for me

```
function myFunction() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh = ss.getSheetByName('Sheet1');
  let s = sh.getRange('D4:E' + sh.getLastRow()).getValues();
  Logger.log(s.map(e => e[1] > 0 ? e[1] - 1 : e[1]));
}
```

You do not require the filter if you simply eliminate the nulls in the first place with lastRow